# Displaying places in wrong position when using google map API

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using the following script to show maps in my application. there are some issues coming :

1. it's displaying only 10 places.
2. it showing provided a place in wrong place.
3. when I want to see only one place then background roadmap is not coming.
4. I want to display on India map but it's not coming.

Please help me out with this issues.

```
var graphVal = Kavitha, Ahmedabad, Gujarat##Chavand, Amreli, Gujarat##Khadol, Anand, Gujarat##Ramgadhi, Arvalli, Gujarat##Vagharol, Banas kantha, Gujarat##Matar, Bharuch       , Gujarat##Patana, Bhavnagar, Gujarat##Dhasa Vishi, Botad       , Gujarat##Panchwada, Dahod, Gujarat##Pimpari, Dang, Gujarat##Rajpar, Devbhumi Dwarka           , Gujarat##Harmadiya
, Gir Somnath   , Gujarat##Jamvanathali;

var mapid = 'map';
var zoomNo = 15;


graphVal = graphVal.replace(/##\s*$/, "");

var graphvalue = graphVal.split('##');
var ccont = graphvalue.length;

var locations = [];

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = '';
var addresArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ccont; i++) {
    var k = 1;
     address = graphvalue[i].replace('SDH', 'Sub District Hospital');
     address = address.replace('DH', 'District Hospital');
     address = address.replace('-', ' ');
   // address = graphvalue[i];
    addresArr[i+1] = graphvalue[i];

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

     //   console.log(results[0]);
        var tempArray = [];
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            var Latitudee = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var Longitudee = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

              tempArray.push(addresArr[k]);
              tempArray.push(Latitudee);
              tempArray.push(Longitudee);
              tempArray.push(k);         
            k++;
        }
        if (typeof tempArray !== 'undefined' && tempArray.length > 0) {
            locations.push(tempArray); 
        } 
    });
}

setTimeout(
    function() 
    {         
        fillMap(locations,mapid,zoomNo);

    }, 1000);


function fillMap(locations,mapid,zoomNo){
    // Setup the different icons and shadows
    var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

    var icons = [
    iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
    iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
    iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
    iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
    iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
    iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',      
    iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
    ]
    var iconsLength = icons.length;    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapid), {
        zoom: zoomNo,
        //scrollwheel: false,
      //  center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.6139, 77.2090),
       // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
        }
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 160
    });

     var markers = new Array();

    var iconCounter = 0;

    // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: icons[iconCounter]
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

        iconCounter++;
        // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
        if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
            iconCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    autoCenter(markers,map);
}
    function autoCenter(markers,map) {
        //  Create a new viewpoint bound
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        //  Go through each...
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
                    bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
        }
        //  Fit these bounds to the map
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

Thanks & Regards,
Asjad